# Is there a way to post to a route automatically if certain conditions are met in per cgi

Tags: javascript, perl, cgi

When a user hits a cgi page if certain conditions are met I want to forward the user to a route via a post request. I tried the below code but I am getting site can't be reached.  Looking through my logs I am getting nothing.

I am getting data from a cgi script in via perl.  If a condition is matched I want to submit to a non cgi route.

```
print qq@<form name='success' action='mysite.com/canyd/' method='post'>@,
qq@<input type='hidden' name='linkB' value='Add Assets' />@,
qq@</form>@,
qq@<script type='text/javascript'>@,
qq@    document.success.submit()@,
qq@</script>@;
```

When the conditions are met and this part of the cgi code fires I just get site can't be reached. I don't need the user to select submit.  Is there a way to maybe use a post module.

What I was expecting would happen is the code would met the condition then take me to the canyd route via the javascript submit.

Comment: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect

Comment: @Grinnz, 307 could be used if and only if the request body is the same for both requests. (It's unclear if that's the case for the OP.)

Comment: The action URL is also wrong as it is path-relative. It should be `//example.com/canyd/` or `https://example.com/canyd/`.

Answer (score 2):

Send the POST request on behalf of the user in your CGI program with the help of a [HTTP client library](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Tiny).

```
use HTTP::Tiny qw();
my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new->post_form(
    'http://‌mysite.com/canyd/',
    { linkB => 'Add Assets' }
);
```